# Re-size div according to window size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to re-size my div according to window size. I have the following code.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#grid1').width('50%'); // <---100% width
    $('#grid1').height('50%'); //<---100% height
});
```

When I run it, scroll bar doesn't appear and my table in the grid is truncated. What should I do?? This is my div

```
<div id="grid1" jsid="grid1" dojoType="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid"
    query="{ name: '*' }"
    data-dojo-props="plugins:{ pagination:{pageSizes: ['10', '25', '50', '100'],
    description: true, sizeSwitch: true, pageStepper: true, gotoButton: true, position: 'bottom', maxPageStep: 7}}, rowsPerPage:10"
    style="height: 300px; width: 930px;">
</div>
</div>
```

This is my DOJO table.

```
    <script>
      dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
      dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Pagination");
      dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
      dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Filter");
      dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");
      dojo.require("dojo.parser"); // scan page for widgets and instantiate them
      var gridLayout = [ 
        {
    name : "S. No.",
    classes : "title",
    width : "70px",
    get : siFormatter,
    filterable : false
}, {
    name : "Site Id",
    classes : "title",
    field : "siteId",
    width : "70px"
}, {
    name : "IP/Phone No.",
    classes : "title",
    field : "devType",
    width : "120px"
}];
</script>
```

Comment: Why not make the div a `%` size in CSS?

Comment: I would say that the grid is inside another container that has a fixed size. But please post the full HTML.

Comment: why not use mediaqueries? This is what they are for. Save using js.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When I use % in CSS< table is truncated. Only a part of the table is visible and scroll bar is not appearing.

Comment: i guess the problem is that you have to put `overflow:scroll;` , that way a scroll bar will appear :)

Comment: When I use overflow:scroll, 2 scroll bars appear. One for the div and another of the DOJO table.

Comment: then just put it for the dojo container !

Comment: How do I apply style for jsid?? Thats my DOJO container

Comment: `#grid1 {overflow:scroll; }` .. or am i missing something

Comment: When I do that, style gets applied for id. Not jsid.

Comment: can you post a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using % is a god habit..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=UTF-8>
  <title>Proportional resizing</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    div {
      position: absolute;
      left: 30%;
      top: 20%;
      width: 40%;
      height: 30%;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>divthing</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `media query` of `css3`

```
#grid1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 930px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  #grid1 {
    height: 150px;
    width: 465px;
  }
}
```

set `height` & `width` values as your requirement.

Comment: Scroll bar is not visible

Comment: there is only option overflow:scroll for Scroll bar. but as u told after in comment, it not works, so i ask for that...